# Need mappings between win32 API and windows store app API

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to convert my old windows app to Windows 8 store app, since windows 8 does not support win32 api, it use windows app store API(a wrapper of win32 api), so I want to know is there a mapping between the two apis? for example I use GetClientRect to get the window's client area in my old app, what's the equivalent in windows 8 api?

Comment: Windows 8 _does_ support the win32 api if you target the desktop.  If you want to target the store, then you will just need to learn the new api.

Comment: It's not even that clear cut since quite a few Win32 APIs can be called directly from a Windows Store app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this list for a reference of supported Win32 functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx) in Windows Store Apps.
Anything beyond those doesn't necessarily have a 1:1 mapping to a new function, so as @mydogisbox suggested, you'll have to learn the new API.